Movie about Fermi & Majorana
I am looking for a movie I watched few years ago in German TV, which I think was about Ettore Majorana and Enrico Fermi.
The scene I can best remember is a student and professor choosing a random exercise from a book and both trying to solve it as quickly as they can. The professor taking half of a large black board and offering the other half to the student. The professor then gets to the answer after having filled his half of the black board while the student is still sitting on his chair not making use of his half. He then trows a little paper with the correct answer towards the professor and wins the competition.
Based on this assumption I think it was "Enrico Fermi - Sein Weg zum Ruhm", original title would be "Ragazzi di via Panisperna" and the English title "Via Panisperna boys". Unfortunately I cannot find it to buy or to rent/stream in any form to confirm this. Is this indeed that movie or another one?

Welcome to Movies & TV. I removed the parts about looking for a stream/download/buying source from the question since this site doesn't entertain such questions. Besides that, can you estimate how many years "few year" are?

For your interest: Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?

You are looking for the Italian movie "I ragazzi di Via Panisperna", directed by Gianni Amelio starring Andrea Prodan in the role of Majorana and Ennio Fantastichini in the role of Fermi.
Here's an excerpt of the plot taken from Wikipedia

The story is inspired by a real life fact and set in the 1930s when, at the Institute of Physics of Via Panisperna, in Rome, physicist Enrico Fermi managed to involve a group of brilliant young students—Emilio, Bruno, Edoardo and Ettore (all of whom became famous scientists)—forming a working group committed to scientific research who would achieve great discoveries in the field of nuclear physics.

And this is the "blackboard duel" scene (in italian) you were referring to:





Thanks but I actually know the movie and the title and had it included in my original post before a moderator messed that up and even removed my actual question.

I've only read the edited version, so I thought you were still in doubt about the movie title. Anyway, if the question was merely about "where can I find it", Napoleon has already explained that such questions are off topic on this site. Have a nice day ;)
